# How can I bind Text property of TextBox (VIEW) to a vaiable (in VIEWMODEL)

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am a newbie in WPF. I was exploring MVVM Pattern for WPF applications. I am having trouble in binding **Text** property of a **TextBox** from VIEW to a variable in **VIEWMODEL**

Here is the TextBox from `MainWindow.xaml`

```
<TextBox x:Name="UsernameTxt" Grid.Row="4" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Username"/>
```

I just need to know how to bind its Text Property to ViewModel Class in Class Library
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible to give a very generic answer to this very generic question.

If the question changes context this answer is very likely to be deleted but here goes anyhow.

You want your viewmodel to be in the datacontext of the textbox. Because datacontext is inherited down the visual tree this usually means you want to set datacontext of your window to an instance of the viewmodel. Or maybe the usercontrol your textbox is in, but we know nothing about your app so let's just cover the simple scenario.

Your options are to instantiate a viewmodel using code or xaml.

If you look at this article:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31915.wpf-mvvm-step-by-step-1.aspx

That instantiates in xaml.

Note the xmlns is

```
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpf_MVVM_Step01"
```

That's saying where you see some bit of markup which is prefaced "local:" then go get the class out of this namespace.

To point to a different dll ( a class library ) you need to tell it which assembly. You do that by adding ;assembly=Whicheverdll to your equivalent of that xmlns. And of course that won't be local then so give it a different name. You also need a reference to that dll or project added to the entry point exe.

Once you've done all that and your viewmodel is instantiated into memory and in the datacontext of that textbox you need some sort of binding.

Which the article covers but that will be something like:

```
  <TextBox Text="{Binding YourPublicStringProperty}"/>
```